# Address individual objects in an ItemsControl template in silverlight & C#

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a silverlight application with an ItemsControl which shows a list of items with values and units assigned to them...

```
Some DataType       1.8 XY
Datatype2          15.6 Units
Other Datatype      1.8 XTZ
```

The issue I have is that the units are custom and hence I cannot know in advance how long they will be and I need them to line up as shown.  So, on the fly, I want to address each of the unit textblocks, find the one with the largest width and set the rest to the same (or set the column to that width).

How can I address each of the textblocks generated in the items control individually in C#?

Here is the xaml so far

```
            <ItemsControl Name="DataTypesGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" Background="{x:Null}" IsEnabled="True">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,2,0,0" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Width="Auto">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="15" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,4,0" FontSize="15" Grid.Column="1" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Unit}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="15" Grid.Column="2" />
                        </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

Thanks for the help

Cap

Answer (score 1):

First get hold of the code for the `VisualTreeEnumeration` extension methods from [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/12/19/visual-tree-enumeration.aspx).

Now add a `Name` property to your unit TextBlock in the data template `Name="unitText"`.

Given the presence of the `VisualTreeEnumeration` extension methods you can now create a "query" for the boxes:-

```
 IEnumerable<TextBlock> unitBlocks = DataTypesGrid.Descendents()
                                  .OfType<TextBlock>()
                                  .Where(t => t.Name == "unitText");
```

You can hang on to `unitBlocks` for as long as `DataTypesGrid` exists.  Using `For Each` on it will return the latest contents of the `ItemsControl`.  You can use `.ToList()` on it if you need to temporarily create a `List<TextBlock>`.

Comment: looks just about spot on, I'll give it a go.  Thanks very much